# How can I decrease the latency to a usable level when I record in Ubuntu Studio?

Tags: ubuntu-studio, jack, audio-recording

I'm having some difficulty smoothing out the latency issues with the newest version of Ubuntu Studio.

I'm using Ubuntu Studio Controls to set configure JACK. The smallest buffer size I can get working without any xruns is 256 with 3 periods so long as I disable the pulse bridge, set the CPU governor to performance, and the Intel Boost off. Unfortunately, this is still unacceptable for doing overdubs in Ardour.

I'm using Ubuntu Studio 22.04.1 LTS with the 5.15.0-57-lowlatency kernal. My interface is a Mackie Onyx 1620i, which has worked beautifully (i.e. no noticeable latency even at the default settings of 1024 buffer size and 2 periods) with all other versions of Ubuntu Studio - hence, my lack of experience/understanding in dealing with the issue. I'm connecting to my computer (a Thinkpad T430s) via a firewire express card.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!